# error in group by clause

Tags: sql, database

im having an error when using group by clause method in my database. This is my code:

```
SELECT A.dvdID  AS 'DVD ID',
A.memberID AS 'MEMBER ID',
B.first_name AS 'FIRST NAME',
B.last_name AS 'LAST NAME',
A.branchID AS 'BRANCH ID',
COUNT(A.dvdID) AS 'Total DVDs Borrowed'
FROM RENT A
JOIN MEMBER B ON (B.memberID = A.memberID)
WHERE A.date_returned = NULL
GROUP BY  A.memberID
ORDER BY last_name ASC;
```

this is the error im getting:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 253
Column 'RENT.dvdID' is invalid in the select list because it is not           
contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

where am i doing wrong?

Comment: On a sidenote: Table aliases shall make the query more readable. Yours do the opposite. Use appropriate alias names, e.g. `r` for `rent` and `m` for `member`, so we don't have to look up again and again what is `A` and what is `B`.

Comment: Another sidenote: Single quotes are delimiters for string constants in SQL. Use double quotes for names (or avoid them completely by only using simple names, such as `total_dvds_borrowed`).

Comment: As to the query: What is the expected result? You group by `memberid`, so you want one result row per member? But which `dvdid` and `branchid` is the query supposed to show then? There can be various rentals and hence multiple branch and DVD IDs per member. Decide if you want to show how many DVDs a member is currently renting (one result row per member), or how often a DVD is currently being rented (one result row per DVD) or how often a member is renting the same DVD at the moment (?) or whatever else you have in mind.

Comment: With SQL questions, you should always tag the DBMS (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, ...) you are asking this for. That's because the answer my differ. An example: `'Total DVDs Borrowed'` is a string constant, where you want it to be an alias name really. That would be `"Total DVDs Borrowed"` in standard SQL (nd most DBMS) Some DBMS however violate the standard here. SQL Server for instance uses brackets instead: `[Total DVDs Borrowed]`.

Answer (score 1):

You should write the query as:

```
SELECT r.memberID,
       m.first_name, m.last_name, r.branchID,
       COUNT(r.dvdID) AS "Total DVDs Borrowed"
FROM RENT r JOIN
     MEMBER m
     ON m.memberID = r.memberID
WHERE r.date_returned IS NULL
GROUP BY r.memberID, m.first_name, m.last_name, r.branchID
ORDER BY last_name ASC;
```

Notes:

- All unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` should be in the `GROUP BY` (this is your explicit error).
- Table aliases should represent the tables they represent, rather than being arbitrary letters.
- Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Don't use them for column aliases.
- The `DVDid` makes no sense in the `SELECT` (your query counts them), so I removed it.
- `= NULL` filters all rows.  The correct SQL syntax is `IS NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

If a column in the select list is not present in the group by clause, then you can only use it within an aggregate function.
If you still want the count along with dvdID together then use the Partition By clause, assuming you are using sql-server.

```
SELECT A.dvdID  AS 'DVD ID',
A.memberID AS 'MEMBER ID',
B.first_name AS 'FIRST NAME',
B.last_name AS 'LAST NAME',
A.branchID AS 'BRANCH ID',
COUNT(A.dvdID) OVER (PARTITION BY A.memberID) AS 'Total DVDs Borrowed'
FROM RENT A
JOIN MEMBER B ON (B.memberID = A.memberID)
WHERE A.date_returned = NULL
ORDER BY last_name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

another alternative to the group by is to pre-query just the count of not-returned rentals and join that to the members list

```
select
      m.first_name AS 'FIRST NAME',
      m.last_name AS 'LAST NAME',
      r.BranchID as 'BRANCH ID',
      r.DVDsBorrowed as 'Total DVDs Borrowed'
   from
      ( select MemberID, 
               BranchID, 
               count(*) DVDsBorrowed
           from 
              rent
           WHERE 
              date_returned IS NULL
           group by 
              MemberID, 
              BranchID ) r
         JOIN Member m
            on r.MemberID = m.MemberID
```

if you actually have an additional branch lookup table and want that description, you can just add something like to the join, and add the branch title to the field list

```
   JOIN Branch b
      on r.BranchID = b.BranchID
```